# Any iControl API equivalent to 'b merge' in BIG-IP?

Tags: f5-big-ip

I want to deploy configurations (virtual server, pools) to my bigip server, based on the files which have same format as /config/bigip.conf.

However, the iControl 'create' API for virtual server and pool only accept string values rather than the whole file, so that I have to parse values from the configuration file, then call the API, which is not straightforward and hard to maintain.

I want to find an iControl API which is equivalent to 'b merge', so that I can load configurations into the system incrementally based on the .conf file.

I don't want to transfer the file to bigip server and do 'b merge' directly for permission issue. Does anyone know if we can do this?

**Reference**

1 [LocalLB::VirtualServer::create](https://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/iControl.LocalLB__VirtualServer__create.ashx)

2 [LocalLB::Pool::create](https://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/iControl.LocalLB__Pool__create.ashx)

Answer (score 1):

The iControl API requires you to perform those `LocalLB::VirtualServer::create` and `LocalLB::Pool::create` actions individually.  There is no 'b merge' equivalent in iControl.

The only real solution options are:

1. Use the `System::ConfigSync::upload_file` API to upload the file and then execute, via an SSH script, the 'b merge' command
2. Parse your input .conf file into its component pieces and create each one using the available iControl commands.

Comment: The 'create' APIs cannot set everything I want to set at once and may bring further maintenance work in the future. The option #1 is the approach I am taking for now. Thanks!